# how to get id from post table rest api?

Tags: php, rest, uri

anyone can help me pls.
i want to make json_encode to get from id

```
localhost/restful/auth/posts/1
```

my code like this

```
@List($objnm, $objid) = explode('/', $_GET['url']);

if ($objnm == "posts")
    {
        $posts = $db->query('SELECT * FROM post');
        echo json_encode($posts, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

        if($objid == "1")
        {
            echo 'susah bnget';
            $id = $db->query('SELECT * FROM post where id=1');
            echo json_encode($id, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        }
    }
```

[get_id_from_post_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Burs9.png)

Comment: It's unclear what are you asking...

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can do so:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];

$chunks = preg_split("#\/#u", $url, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$count = count($chunks);
$lastChunk = $chunks[$count-1];

// Detect: use findAll or FindOneById
if (is_numeric($lastChunk)){
    $id = $lastChunk;
    $entityName = $chunks[$count-2];
} else {
    $id = null;
    $entityName = $chunks[$count-1];
}

// Create sql query string
$sql = "SELECT * FROM";
switch ($entityName) {
    case "posts":
        $sql .= ' post';
    break;
    case "something_else":
        $sql .= ' something_else';
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("$entityName doesn't expected");
}
if (!is_null($id)) {
    $sql .= " WHERE id = $id";
}

$result = $db->query($sql);
echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```